# Getting Error while initializing sparkR : JVM is not ready after 10 seconds

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop2, sparkr

I'm currently testing one application using sparkR. This are the my platform & application details:

> Platform: Windows server 2008 SparkR version : R version 3.1.2
>   (2014-10-31) Spark Verion :   version 1.4.1

What I did?

**Step I: Load package into R environment**

> library(SparkR) -- Working

**Step II: Set the system environment variables**

> Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:\hdp\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6") --
>   Working .libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R",
>   "lib"),.libPaths()))

**Step III: Create a spark context and a SQL context**

> sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local",sparkHome =
>   "C:\hdp\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6",appName = "TestSparR")

Getting error at this line i.e  **JVM is not ready after 10 seconds**

Please, help me resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: [SPARK-8603](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8603)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I can tell you I tried many many things.

But finally the following worked for me, **after restarting my computer (and R and RStudio by the way)**:

```
SPARK_HOME <- "C:\\Apache\\spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6\\"
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0" "sparkr-shell"')
library(SparkR, lib.loc = "C:\\Apache\\spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6\\R\\lib")

library(SparkR)
library(rJava)

sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local", sparkHome = SPARK_HOME)
```

Maybe this can help: after restarting the system this was included in my environment variables PATH:

**C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
sparkPath <- 'C:/Users/YOUR PATH'
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME=sparkPath)
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME'), 'R', 'lib'), .libPaths()))
library(SparkR)
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master='local')
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, it may be because you have a space in your path. example    
    C:/Users/Rick Ross/etc., when you have a space in your path is sometimes glitchy. Try installing Docker!